# Can Control.Invoke() be interrupted?

Tags: c#, .net

When calling `Control.Invoke()`, it blocks the calling thread until the message gets processed. I am wondering if I can break out of this block from another thread.

**Note:** I know that I can use `Control.BeginInvoke()`, but I am not asking about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot.

The waiting thread decides the set of conditions that wake it.

If you want the option to interrupt a cross-thread call, you can use a `ManualResetEvent`, the `WaitHandle` from `BeginInvoke`, and `WaitAny`.

Note that if you do this and then wake from the wait using the event, it will not dequeue the cross-thread call.  The worker thread simply won't wait for it any longer.

Answer (score 0):

> ...if I can break out of this block from another thread

`Control.Invoke()` will run on the UI thread which is the main thread.  If you kill it, you will exit the application.

To prevent the UI threading from blocking too long, you should only perform action in `Control.Invoke()` that is updating the control only.  Anything else should be done else place.